# Google Scripts message to discord. How to make it more efficient

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got this code to send the message, but I know that there has to be a more efficient way to do so, rather than a new message for every section.  Trying it that way is overloading the webhook and causing me to be rate limited.

I've edited to include the full code, minus the webhook URLs.  I'm fairly new to coding, so I'm sure it's a mess, but I know it was at least working up to a point because I was testing as I went.  It's mainly the sending back part that isn't working how I intended.

````
function Insert_Checks() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ws = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var range = ws.getRange(2,2,ws.getLastRow() - 1)
  var rangec = range.offset(0,1)
  rangec.insertCheckboxes()
}
function Supply_Order_Complete() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var ws = ss.getActiveSheet()
    var range = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow())
    num_rows = Logger.log(range.getNumRows())
    const rows = ws.getDataRange().getValues()
    var headers = rows.shift();
    var ordered = []
    var subs = []
    var notes = []

    rows.forEach(function(row) {
      i = 0
      if(row[2] || row[4] != "") {
        ordered.push(row[1].getValue)
        subs.push(row[3].getValue)
        notes.push(row[4].getValue)
      }
      while (i <= ordered.length) {
        var currentMessage = []
        currentMessage.push("'ordered[i]' - 'subs[i]' - 'notes[i]'\n")
        i = i + 1
    }
    Send_Order(currentMessage)
    });
}
function Send_Order(currentMessage) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ws = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var wsn = ws.getName()
  if (wsn === "9th") {
    url = 
  }
  if (wsn === "Apartments") {
    url = 
  }
  if (wsn === "Billings") {
    url = 
  }
  if (wsn === "ElmA") {
    url = 
  }
  if (wsn === "ElmB") {
    url = 
  }
  if (wsn === "Knollview") {
    url = 
  }
  if (wsn === "Centennial") {
    url = '
  }
  if (wsn === "Michigan") {
    url = 
  }
  if (wsn === "Scammon") {
    url = 
  }
  if (wsn === "Adams") {
    url = 
  }
  if (wsn === "Test") {
    url = 
  }
  const message = {
    content: currentMessage
  }
  const options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : message
  }
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
}```

What I am getting on Discord is this: 
[Ljava.lang.Object;@2eced131
[Ljava.lang.Object;@5b8e5a90
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1b09921c
[Ljava.lang.Object;@4037c438
[Ljava.lang.Object;@24727d3e

Each one being a separate message rather than one message.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmWJH.png
````

Comment: Please share a [sample sheet data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to properly replicate your script.

Comment: Here is the exact message I'm getting 

7:14:41 PM Error 
Exception: Request failed for https://discord.com returned code 429. Truncated server response: {
  "global": false, 
  "message": "You are being rate limited.", 
  "retry_after": 1228
}
 (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
Send_Order @ Code.gs:78
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:31
Supply_Order_Complete @ Code.gs:19

The goal is to condense the messages into one message then send it back to the correct channel.   I'll edit my post with the full script and a screenshot of what I'm using it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, it seems that you want to use the WebHook URL by the active sheet. And, it seems that you want to send the values like `"column B" - "column D" - "column E"` when the values of columns "B" or "E" are existing. I understood your goal like this.
- When I saw your script, I thought that the script of `rows.forEach(function(row) {,,,})` is required to be used. For example, I think that `row[#].getValue` is `undefined`. And, `currentMessage` is `[ '\'ordered[i]\' - \'subs[i]\' - \'notes[i]\'\n' ]`. I think that this is the reason for `[Ljava.lang.Object;@###`.
- And, in order to avoid the error of `You are being rate limited.`, how about using "embeds"? [Ref](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/structure/embed/fields.html#fields)

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please set your WebHook URLs for each key of `obj`.

```js
function sample() {
  // Please set URLs to obj.
  const obj = {
    "9th": "###url###",
    "Apartments": "###url###",
    "Billings": "###url###",
    "ElmA": "###url###",
    "ElmB": "###url###",
    "Knollview": "###url###",
    "Centennial": "###url###",
    "Michigan": "###url###",
    "Scammon": "###url###",
    "Adams": "###url###",
    "Test": "###url###"
  };

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rows = ws.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const fields = rows.reduce((ar, row, i) => {
    if (row[2] || row[4]) {
      ar.push({ name: i + 1, value: `${row[1]} - ${row[3]} - ${row[4]}\n` });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  const max = 25;
  const splitted = [...Array(Math.ceil(fields.length / max))].map(_ => fields.splice(0, max));
  const url = obj[ws.getSheetName()];
  if (url) {
    splitted.forEach(fields => {
      var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { payload: JSON.stringify({ content: "", embeds: [{ fields }] }), contentType: "application/json" });
      Utilities.sleep(5000); // Please adjust this wait time.
    });
    return;
  }
  console.log(`There is no URL of '${ws.getSheetName()}'.`);
}
```

- The values of `name` and `value` of `{ name: i + 1, value:` ${row[1]} - ${row[3]} - ${row[4]}\n `}` are the sample values. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Note:

- In this case, 25 items are the maximum number of items for `embeds`. So, in this sample script, the values are sent every 25 rows. And, a wait time of `Utilities.sleep(5000)` is used for every request.

  - Please adjust the wait time of `5000` for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: That works great, thank you!  I have no idea what you did with half of it though lol, a lot of learning to do still.  I've mostly been learning python, but need to pick up JS since a lot of google is done with that.

Comment: @Xiael Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var vs = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2).getValues().map((r, i) => {
    if (!r[2] || !r[4]) {
      return [r[1], r[3], r[4]]
    }
  }).filter(e => e[0]);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @AdrianMole I basically disagree with your link.  If people want to copy the code and run they will; if they wish to learn they will do what I do with the answers of others.  I disregard the explanations and dig into the code and figure it out for myself with the reference material that is available to me and that's what I expect others to do.  We are all students in this world.  There need not be any teachers amongst us. In my opinion the best teachers are mere students who share there results.  And that's what I do.  I share my results

Comment: Sure - You are completely entitled to that point-of-view. But note that this question found its way into the "Low Quality Answers" review queue (where I found it). That review completed with two reviewers (including myself) giving it a "Looks OK" verdict, but one reviewer chose to recommend deletion. Just FYI.

Comment: @AdrianMole  Perhaps teachers are interested in earning points.  I'm more interest in gaining knowledge and I'm willing to step out and make the commitment to an answer knowing full well that if I am totally wrong someone will provide a better answer that I can learn from.  Tanaike provided that answer today when he used the new removeDuplicates() method of range which I did not know about.  I don't need any explanation from him.  The information is well documented online and I'm not a lazy student. I'm more interested in learning than I am teaching.